# Why can't my .exe ALWAYS write a file from a webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7.5, asmx, processstartinfo

This is an issue that has me pulling my hair out. 
**TL:DR;** IIS 7.5 webservice calls .exe which writes a file. Works when I navigate to the .asmx page (not in debug/cassini, actual IIS in chrome/FF) but doesn't work when I call the service from an applicaiton. Eventually this webservice call will need to come from a windows service call.

---

```
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        //      Use the UTMs as the corners for the projwin in the gdal_translate call below                                  
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        string sExecutionFile = string.Empty;
        if ((ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BIN_PATH"]!=null) && File.Exists(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BIN_PATH"] + "/gdal_translate.exe"))
            sExecutionFile = Path.Combine(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BIN_PATH"],"gdal_translate.exe");
        else
            sExecutionFile = "gdal_translate.exe";

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(sExecutionFile,
            "-projwin " + pointUL[0] + " " + pointUL[1] + " " +
             pointLR[0] + " " + pointLR[1] + " " +
            sImageFileName + " " + sResultsFileName);

        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

        using(myProcess = new Process())
        {
         myProcess.StartInfo = psi;
         myProcess.Start();
         myProcess.WaitForExit();
         myProcess.Close();
         myProcess.Dispose();
        }
```

---

The above code calls a small exe to generate a TIFF from another TIFF file. It's in a DLL wrapped up in a webservice call. I've got everything working and I can go to my localhost server, run the "DataService.asmx" page I created, fill out the form and biggity-bam, I have a TIFF in my new directory (also created by the webservice). I then wrote a small command-line applicaiton to attempt to call the webservice. It happily calls the webservice and a few others I tried for testing purposes. The problem is that I get the new directory created, but there's never any TIFF files inside of it. After debugging, my code is complaining that above code didn't create a file. **What am I missing?**

I've tried a variety of IIS 7.5 config options as well as OS-level permissions on the relevant directories. Going all the way up to "LocalSystem" yields the same behavior as going down to "AppPoolIdentity", "IUSR"... I have to believe that the above code is failing, even if it's not throwing any exceptions at all. Is there a better way to debug a ProcessStartInfo call from an IIS webservice? I could understand if this didn't work at all, or if I had to run it as an Admin account to get it to work, but the call works when I invoke it directly from the .asmx page.

Comment: What line does it fail at? Also, I recommend using String.Format instead of that ugly block of text there.

Comment: "What am I missing?" I tell you what _we_ are missing: proper info about any error messages. Have you try/catch logged the server code? Have you try/catch logged any exception on the client side? How does this client code of yours connect? What credentials is it using? What is the authentication model on the server? Do you use impersonation?

Comment: Ah yes, the error handling. There's no failure thrown in any of this so I'm going to have to implement [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to catch anything. The client code happily calls this service and works fine. Credentials? I honestly have tried about every permutation of user/pass, LocalSystem, LocalService,NetworkService,IUSR, Impersonation, Anonymous Authentication and none of them made any difference.